# Sleeving the dollar cards in Ca$h 'n Guns where the exact sleeve size doesn't exist

Tags: card-sleeves, cash-n-guns

I've recently received Ca$h 'n Guns (2nd edition) for my birthday, and I'm sleeving all the cards. The problem is that the "dollars" card have a very weird size (`60x120` mm, or `2.36x4.72` in) and I can't find sleeves of the right size. I want to cover them, since those are the most used cards of the game.

The closest I've found (and the recommended one by most sites) are the [Tarot](https://www.amazon.it/75-Mayday-67-Rings-CE-Special/dp/B00BKNODVI/) size (`70x120` mm, `2.76x4.72` in), which are 1 cm bigger on one dimension, or a [smaller](https://www.amazon.it/Mayday-Games-MDG7113-Protettive-61x112/dp/B007Q0PLLK/) one (`61x112` mm, `2.40x4.41` in).

What would you do? Use the bigger size sleeves or do some complicated stuff like having a smaller sleeve on one side of the card and another on the other side, with an overlapping section?

Comment: Honestly, I would just buy a second copy of the game. You're talking about a potential cost of $15-20 (for double sleeves) to protect the components that are handled the *least* (besides the diamond, of course). Furthermore, damaged cards would have almost no impact on the game, unless you're playing with card counters... but then just shoot the card counter!

Comment: Why would you say those are the least used cards? I have yet to play a game (I have received it just a few days ago), so my judgment is mostly based on reading the rules, but I think that, after the Bang/Click cards, the rewards one are quite used. You think I'm making a big deal out of nothing?

Comment: The cards are certainly *essential* - they just aren't *handled* that much. Each card is shuffled at the beginning, dealt out and chosen during one round, and kept in a player's "stash" until the end of the game.

Comment: Ok, I'm wrapping my head on nothing :D Thanks for the advice, @TheChaz2.0 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the comments in an answer so we can "close" the case.

---

*Honestly, I would just buy a second copy of the game. You're talking about a potential cost of $15-20 (for double sleeves) to protect the components that are handled the least (besides the diamond, of course). Furthermore, damaged cards would have almost no impact on the game, unless you're playing with card counters... but then just shoot the card counter!*

*The cards are certainly essential - they just aren't handled that much. Each card is shuffled at the beginning, dealt out and chosen during one round, and kept in a player's "stash" until the end of the game.*